# Hawaiian earring is not homotopy equivalent to cone over subspace of $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X = [0, 1]$, let $A = \{0\} \cup \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Let $CA$ denote the cone on $A$. The spaces $X/A$ (the Hawaiian earring) and $X \cup CA$ are not homotopy equivalent; one way to see this is that their first homology groups are different.
$$
H_1(X\cup CA) = \widetilde {H}_1(X, A) \preceq \bigoplus_1^\infty \mathbb{Z}$$
where the second inclusion comes from considering the long exact sequence of homology of the pair $(X, A)$. On the other hand $H_1(X/A)$ is well-known to be uncountable and contains $\prod_1^\infty \mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup.

Is there an intuitive purely topological reason why the two spaces are not homotopy equivalent?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's an intuitive argument that their fundamental groups aren't the same:  both spaces have infinitely many loops, but in $X/A$ any neighborhood of the special point contains all but finitely many of the loops, while in $X \cup CA$ the loops are all "large".  So it's possible to traverse all the loops consecutively in the former, but not in the latter.

Comment: @RaviFernando that's along the lines of what I'm looking for. I understand why small loops make it possible to traverse the loops consecutively (basically this ensures continuity of at the end of the loop). Could you elaborate on why we can't construct some way of traversing all the large loops in finite time?

Comment: I'm now realizing that it depends on how exactly my claim is interpreted: in a sense, just going around the perimeter of $X \cup CA$ does traverse all the loops. But I claim it's possible to order the loops in such a way that we must return to the special point between each pair. (For example, never do adjacent loops consecutively.) Then choose such times $t_1 < t_2 < \cdots$ when we're at the special point, and let $t$ be the limit of a convergent subsequence. In any interval around $t$, we must both stay near the special point and traverse infinitely many loops, contradiction.

Comment: This makes sense. I'd be happy to accept if you made it into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental group actually has a reasonable topology that makes it into a topological space. You topologize it as the quotient of the based mapping space by the equivalence relation generated by paths (AKA homotopies of loops).

For CW complexes, this topology will always be discrete, but for other spaces, like the ones you give, they do not have to be. Since you aren’t asking about pointed homotopy equivalence, let’s use the analogous unpointed fundamental set of homotopy classes of loops.

In the Hawaiian earring, there is a sequence of essential loops that converges to a constant loop, but in your other space it is clear that if we metrize it in a reasonable way, every essential loop has to be relatively long because it must wrap around a triangle with fixed height.

This argument can be formalized to show that no sequence of essential loops converges to the constant loop in the space you describe. Since any map of path connected spaces necessarily preserves the homotopy class of the constant loop, we know that any map between your two spaces fails to be a homotopy equivalence, since if it was it would induce a pointed homeomorphism between the fundamental sets. However, we just showed the basepoints were topologically different.

Comment: Since I'm somewhat new to the subject, bear with me while I try to understand this. To clarify, 1) The (unpointed) mapping space is the set of loops into $X$, topologised with the compact open topology, 2) take its quotient by homotopy equivalence of maps to get something akin to an unpointed fundamental group, and call it (say) $\pi(X)$ 3) a homotopy equivalence $X \to Y$ must induce a homeomorphism $\pi(X) \to \pi(Y)$, 4) for the spaces given above, $\pi(X)$ and $\pi(Y)$ are not homeomorphic. In other words $\pi(X)$ is functorial from $\mathrm{hTop}$ to $\mathrm{Top}$.

Comment: I don't understand point (4) though. "No sequence of essential loops converges to the constant loop". We need to show that no sequence of essential loops converges to the *homotopy class* of the constant loop in $X\cup CA$, and I don't see how to do that. The homotopy class of the constant loop can include non-constant loops, like the loop from $0$ to the cone tip and back.

Comment: @abhi01nat Good point, in fact you do have such a sequence. I will think more about if the topology distinguishes them.

Comment: Switching back to fundamental groups: if you alter the topology a bit, you end up with a topological group. When you have a topological group, you can talk about infinite sums and whether they converge or not. In the Hawaiian earring, there are many infinite sums that converge, which is part of what makes the fundamental group so interesting. In this cone example, I don’t believe any nontrivial infinite sums should converge. This is basically how a formalization of Ravi’s argument might go.

Comment: As for how to prove that, you should suppose that we have a loop that winds around infinitely many circles, and then take a point in each one of these loops and show the sequence converges to multiple points.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense - so ultimately it does come down to a somewhat algebraic invariant as opposed to an elementary topological argument. But that's okay, I suppose I need to accept the algebraic viewpoint as a different ontology.

Comment: @abhi01nat It is at the very least much less algebraic than calculating the homology of the Hawaiian earring. At the same time it is also much easier, and it doesn’t rely purely on not having an isomorphism of groups, but rather not having an isomorphism of topological groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive argument that their fundamental groups aren't the same; Connor Malin's answer is more rigorous.  Both spaces have infinitely many loops, but in $X/A$ any neighborhood of the special point contains all but finitely many of the loops, while in $X \cup CA$ the loops are all "large".  So in the former it's possible to continuously traverse all the loops consecutively in any order (for example, spending $1/2^n$ units of time traversing the $n$th loop).  I claim this is not the case in $X \cup CA$.  (Note that this doesn't really prove $X/A \not\simeq X \cup CA$, since it requires us to assume that the $n$th loop in $X/A$ corresponds to the $n$th loop in $X \cup CA$, and also to pretend that infinite products make sense in $\pi_1$.  The latter issue can be solved by topologizing the fundamental group as in Connor's answer.)

Although the loops in $X \cup CA$ share edges, they can be ordered in such a way that we must return to the special point between each pair. (For example, never do adjacent loops consecutively.)  Then suppose we have a path that traverses all the loops in such an order, choose times $t_1 < t_2 < \cdots$ when we're at the special point between loops, and let $t$ be the limit of a convergent subsequence. In any interval around $t$, we must both stay near the special point (by continuity) and traverse infinitely many loops (by construction), which is a contradiction.